# How to make selection highlight transparent in fabricjs IText?

Tags: javascript, css, fabricjs, jscolor

I'm using jscolor-colorpicker with fabricjs-IText in a way that gives me a live preview of the color on mouse-move. The only thing not cool now is that the semitransparent selection highlighting is messing up the colorpreview in text-edit mode. Any ideas on how to remove the selection highlighting or make the selection totally transparent?

I can't find any properties in the jsdoc relating to the selection color!? http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.IText.html

```
<input value="ffcc00"  id="fill" class="jscolor {onFineChange:'itext_setcolor(this)',hash:true}">

window.itext_setcolor = function(val) {
        obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
        if (obj) {
            if (obj.isEditing) {
                 setStyle(obj, 'fill', '#' +val); 
            } else 
            {  
                obj.setFill('#' + val);
            }
          canvas.renderAll();
        }  
 };
```

**EDIT 1**

Thank's @STHayden for giving me the right answer. Here's the final working code with reappearance of the highlighting when text selection changes.

```
...
  canvas.on('text:selection:changed', onTextChangedIText);
...
  function onTextChangedIText() {
       var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
        if (obj.selectionStart>-1) {
            obj.set({'selectionColor':'rgba(17,119,255,0.3)'}); 
        }
    } 

 window.itext_setcolor = function(val) {
         obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
        if (obj) {
            if (obj.isEditing) {
                 obj.set({'selectionColor':'transparent'});
                 setStyle(obj, 'fill', '#' +val); 
            } else
            {  
                obj.setFill('#' + val);
            }
            canvas.renderAll();
        }  
    };
```

Comment: This is not an iText® question. See the [iText documentation on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/itext/) to learn about the technology that can be tagged as an iText question. The guys from fabricjs used the trademarked name iText for something completely different, causing unnecessary confusion.

Comment: Ok! iText tag removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a lot of options. The property on IText for the selection color is `selectionColor` and you can set it to be fully transparent with the keyword `transparent` or an rgba value: `rgba(0,0,0,0)`.

If you get the reference to the IText object you can also do a few things:

1. Change the `startSelection` and `endSelection` to 0.
2. Call the `.exitEditing()` function on the IText object.
3. Just remove the IText object as the active object with `.discardActiveObject()`

when you are done letting the user pick a color you can set the selection back to what it was.

Comment: selectionColor worked but none of the other solutions where usable in this case. They all destroys the selection and thereby also the editing. But thumbs up on selectionColor :-)

Comment: yes... for 1 and 2 you would need to set the `startSelection` and `endSelection` back to the previous state after color picking was done.